# X509Certificate2 ctor with cer file

Tags: .net, ssl, passwords, certificate, x509certificate2

I'm facing some issue with 2-way ssl configuration in .Net.
Somehow, when I create X509Certificate2 object using .cer file and password in the constructor, the password is ignored (I gave wrong password and it worked - the response was successfully returned).
In the other hand, when I use .p12 file the behavior is as expected (wrong password causes unsuccessful result)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .cer file contains (it is the common case) only the X509 certificate in an unencrypted form. In that case, no password is required to decode the certificate. I suppose the X509Certificate2 constructor tries to determine the encoding format of the Byte[] parameter and ignore the password parameter when it is not required. And it is more than likely that, after being created, the `PrivateKey` property of the object is `null`.

When loading a .cer file you should use the constructor which takes only 1 Byte[] parameter. The documentation of that constructor clearly specifies the supported data formats:

> This constructor creates a new X509Certificate2 object using certificate information from a byte array. The byte array can be binary (DER) encoded or Base64-encoded X.509 data. The byte array can also be a PKCS7 (Authenticode) signed file; the signer certificate is used to create the object.

The [PKCS#12 format](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2138) (.p12 or .pfx file) is a container format for certificates and private keys. In that case the password is required to decrypt the encrypted private key. Actually the behaviour with a PKCS#12 file is specified in the The X509Certificate2 constructor documentation:

> This constructor is used with PKCS12 (PFX) files that contain the certificate's private key. Calling this constructor with the correct password decrypts the private key and saves it to a key container.

Comment: +1. .cer files are used to store public keys usually, as discussed in http://www.lextm.com/2012/02/simple-publicprivate-key-signing-sample.html

Comment: link seems to have changed to http://www.lextm.com/index.php/2012/02/simple-publicprivate-key-signing-sample-code/