# .Net Core + Kubernettes > AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm working on several Dotnet Core APIs hosted on a Kubernettes cluster and some of the APIs do call other APIs, and that's when the exception in title is thrown.

It doesn't matter whether I edit the appsettings.json and replace all https by http -in fact people at devops team suggested me to do that- as the same exception is thrown.

This is the little piece of code I use for the http call:

```
int idCity = Convert.ToInt32(Utils.GetConfig().GetSection("Settings")["idCity"]);

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Utils.GetConfig().GetSection("xxx")["xxxx"]);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string queryString = "?startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate + "&idCity=" + idCity;

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(queryString).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var resultHolidays = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONGeneric<HolidayDTO>>(resultHolidays);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have a copy of the certificate in .crt format and also tried:

```
string certPath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, _configuration.GetSection("Certificate")["certificatePath"]);
string pwd = _configuration.GetSection("Certificate")["certificatePwd"];

HttpClientHandler requestHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certPath, pwd,
    X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet));

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(requestHandler))
{
    ...
}
```

To no avail, as the same exception is thrown.

I'm not an expert on working with certificates, but I truly need to make this to work, to be able to make on api in a pod call other api, so any help will be much appreciated.

Update 1: The "weird" thing is that if I just copy the url to be requested -no matter if you use http or https- and paste it into a browser with the certificate installed it does work. If you copy and paste the http version of the url n the browser, Kubernettes (or whoever it is) does a redirection to the https version but in the end you get results. **Not from .Net**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by disabling certificate validation in the client and see what is the behavior. You can do it like this:

```cs
var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, crt, chn, e) => true
};

using var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
// rest of the code
```

If the call succeeds, the next step is to adapt the certificate validation callback to check the server's certificate.

*Note: in your example you're configuring a client certificate, which is useful if you host a service and want to authorize your clients based on their certificates, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-your-host-to-require-certificates). From the problem description I understand that what you need is the opposite: validate the server certificate in your client.*

```cs
var srvCrt = new X509Certificate2(certPath, pwd);

var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, crt, chn, e) => {
        return crt.Thumbprint == srvCrt.Thumbprint;
    }
};

using var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
// rest of the code
```

Comment: Hello @M. F., I appreciate very much your help. Firstly I'll say disabling certificate validation works, so it's a good start (maybe), but with the second piece of code (attaching the certificate) it does not work with the same "SSL connection problem error".

Comment: The certificate DevOps has sent to me is in crt format, is it OK for the code you've written?

Comment: Hello @DiegoPerez, glad to hear that at least it works when certificate validation is disabled. Regarding certificate format, please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957209/x509certificate2-ctor-with-cer-file). You should also check that the certificate is correct, meaning that it is the one used by the services you're trying to consume.